# How to insert in Collection within a Fiber

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Trying to create a new entry in the DB, but I keep getting an error about my code not being in a fiber. I have no idea what the problem could be. I must add that I am doing the insert on the server side. This is not a Method call from a client.

Here is my code.

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';





export const Trxs = new Mongo.Collection('trx');

export const addTrx = (trxn, userId) => {

    var date = new Date(trxn.date).valueOf();
    var userId = userId;
    var catID = trxn.category_id;
    var amt = trxn.amount;
    var trx_name = trxn.name;

    console.log(trxn);

    Trxs.insert({
        date,
        userId,
        catID,
        amt,
        trx_name
    });
}
```

And this is the error I am getting.

> Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping
>   callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with
>   Meteor.bindEnvironment.

Comment: Have you tried it without an arrow function? Because Fibers work with a particular context, it might not work in an arrow function...?

Comment: Still getting the same issue without an arrow function.

Comment: `Meteor.bindEnvironment` should do the trick

Comment: Put everthing in Meteor.method then call method from anywhere.. console/shell, client or server.

Comment: If you must work outside a Meteor method and you have to make a call to a Mongo Collection (for example you write a package that includes common code) you will need to wrap the method using `bindEnvironment`.

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya how can I call the method from the server side if I put it in a Meteor.method?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I tried using the bindEnvironment, but that didn't work. I must have used it incorrectly. 

Can you show me what modification with BindEnvironment would make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is used as callback or is called within a callback on the server, then it looses the Meteor environment's context.

This is often the case when dealing with async functions on the server. The error above occurs, because there is also a call `Mongo.Collection` methods (which are not raw Mongo calls but have been rewritten according to the Meteor environment).

You need to wrap it therefore by using `Meteor.bindEnvironment`. You can reproduce this easily:

**trx.js**

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Trxs = new Mongo.Collection('trx');

export const addTrx = Meteor.bindEnvironment((trxn, userId) => {

    var date = new Date(trxn.date).valueOf();
    var userId = userId;
    var catID = trxn.category_id;
    var amt = trxn.amount;
    var trx_name = trxn.name;

    Trxs.insert({
        date,
        userId,
        catID,
        amt,
        trx_name
    });
});
```

**main.js**

```
import {addTrx, Trxs} from "./modc";


setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("call")
    addTrx({
        category_id: "12312321",
        amount: 10000,
        name: "foo",
    }, '123123123')
}, 5000);
```

If you would remove the `bindEnvironment` wrapping of the function, the code in *main.js* will throw the same Error, that you received.

Resources for further reading:

https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment

https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection